How to prevent isAllDay events spanning multiple day when querying devices calendar SwiftUI
I assume the issue is daylight savings. I just can't figure out a fix
My setup. I have a schedule view. on which I want to display the users Calendar events on. Each day in the schedule queries for any events using
func fetchSystemCalendarEventForDate(_ date: Date) -> [EKEvent]{
       
        let calendars = CalendarManager.sharedInstance.eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
        let predicate = CalendarManager.sharedInstance.eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: date, end: date.endOfDay, calendars: calendars)
        return CalendarManager.sharedInstance.eventStore.events(matching: predicate).filter({$0.calendar.title != "myAppCal" })
    }

The date passed in has time of 00:00:00
the .endOfDay modifier sets the time to 23:59:00
If for example the 26th July 2024 was queried and it returns an EKEvent the user has set to be allDay. It is also returned when the 25th July 2024 queries the fetchSystemCalendarEventForDate(_ date: Date) function.
If I try moving the date for the withStart argument ahead 2 hours with .addingTimeInterval(7200). It Still shows on both the 26th and 25th.
The When printing out the event.startDate & event.endDate
I get

00:00 23:59 25 July 2024
as expected. Only this is also what is printed out for 26th July even though the event ended 23:59 the day before.

endOfDay is
extension Date {
var endOfDay: Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = 23
        components.minute = 59
        components.second = 59
 
        return Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(byAdding: components, to: self)!
    }
}

date passed in as is

2024-07-26 00:00:00

Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).startOfDay(for: date)


2024-07-25 23:00:00

Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).startOfDay(for: date).addingTimeInterval(TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London")!.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: date))


2024-07-26 00:00:00

so if I was passing in date as is or even modified for DLS they are both 2024-07-26 00:00:00.
It would only be if using
Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).startOfDay(for: date)
would I then be passing in the wrong start time.

Can you show how you calculate endOfDay. If your calculation doesn't involve Calendar then it is going to be wrong.

@Paulw11 it is using the Calendar in a Date Extension

How do you know that your input date is the correct start of the day?  You should use startOfDay from Calendar. Adding time in hours and minutes is also dangerous because of daylight savings.  I would suggest you add 1 day to the date you get from startOfDay and use a < in your predicate

DLS is the issue.
let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
print(cal.startOfDay(for: date)) // ... 23:00:00

That's probably correct if your Timezone is utc+1. Dates print in utc
